# Add AutoMapper package visual studio 2015 RC : crash

Tags: c#, automapper, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I have 5 projects in my solution, 
I need to add  automapper to my Asp.Net MV4 web project : 
In the nugget package console I typed
"install-package AutoMapper -ProjectName"

And visual studio keeps on crashing. 
Did someone got the same behaviour ?

Comment: I'm using VS2015 RTM rather than RC but certainly fine on there.

Comment: Will do the upgrade : 
Don't you think there is something to do with the solution type (vs2012)

Comment: The project I'm working with is from VS2013 rather than VS2012 but wouldn't have thought it would make a great deal of difference.  Must admit, I tend to use the package manager GUI rather than the console for adding packages generally, but trying console in this instance worked fine.  I just removed automapper and tried to add it using package manager console and it added fine.

Comment: I'm upgrading my Nuget.Tools version seems 
there is a hot fix https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1572078/nuget-crash-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise

Thank you Chris